# Proving $\lim_{y\to0, y>0}\frac{y}{\pi}\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx=f(0)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Show that for every bounded and continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
$$\lim_{y\to0, y>0}\frac{y}{\pi}\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx=f(0)$$.

Could someone please give me a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the integral as

$$ \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(x)}{\frac{x^2}{y^2} + 1} \frac{dx}{y} $$

which makes the substitution $u = \frac{x}{y}$ obvious

$$ \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(yu)}{u^2+1} du \to \frac{f(0)}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^2+1} du = f(0) $$

I'll leave it to you to figure out why taking the $R$ limit beforehand is justified and to justify the moving of the $y$ limit inside the integral.